# Make inner element align right on overflow

Tags: css, position, overflow

I have a div inside a div. The `.outer` div has overflow set to hidden and is 200px wide. The `.inner` div is 300px wide and hides fine per the `overflow` spec.

What I'd like to do is find a way to align the inner div so that it cuts off the overflow on the left side instead of the right.

I could use positioning and negative margins but ultimately the inner div is variable width, so I'm hoping there's a way to accomplish this without 'hard-coding' anything?

Here's the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/xCYPc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `float: right;` on the `.inner`

Comment: Actually, there's still an issue - everything goes right - see http://jsfiddle.net/xCYPc/1/ - I'd like so only the overflow has this action.

Comment: I'm thinking I may need to use JS to calculate the outer and inner, then apply `float: right` if the condition is met...

Comment: I agree. You can't really determine width and flip the float back and forth using CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `direction: rtl` to your `.outer` div, see working [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kCwr8/)

From http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/direction :

> The direction property specifies the base writing direction of blocks
>   and the direction of embeddings and overrides for the Unicode
>   bidirectional algorithm.
>
> Also, it specifies the direction of table column layout, the direction
>   of horizontal overflow, and the position of an incomplete last line in
>   a block in case of 'text-align: justify'.

Answer (score 0):

Make `.outer` `position:relative` and `.inner` `position:absolute;right:0`. That will keep the inner div aligned right regardless of its width.